# Transformation of machineKey tag

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables, release-management, web.config-transform

We have to transform  tag in which "decryptionKey" and "validationKey" will be different for our development and test environments.

We have tried to give different variables for validationKey and decryptionKey but confused with the xdt: Transform and xdt: Locator attribute as they will occur once in the same tag.

Suppose following is the web.config machineKey tag,

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="012345678910111213141516"
            validation="SHA1"                validationKey="235487512547896321458778996325456965542126364586965" />
```

We have to give transformation something like following,

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="#{DecryptionKey}#"
            validation="SHA1"
            validationKey="#{ValidationKey}#"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
            xdt:Locator="Match(decryptionKey)"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
            xdt:Locator="Match(validationKey)" />
```

Need this kind of a solution in which we have to give multiple variables within a single tag.

Answer (score 0):

To set multiple attributes, you need to pass them into SetAttributes as a comma-delimited list.

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110))

However, if you are actually replacing all of the attributes, it might just be easier/cleaner to use `xdt:Transform="Replace"` and set the entire tag value in each configuration.